# How can I possibly get Sales and Order info from Merch by Amazon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

I am relatively new in using Amazon's APIs. I am trying to get Sales and Orders information for Merch by Amazon in Ruby on Rails. How can I possibly do that .I have researched a lot but unable to find any answers as Merch is a new platform, they do give developer api but for advertisement of my current products apparently. Is there any third party api or any way so I can get the sales and order's data of my Merch account in RoR. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple what you have to do.  First you must sign up for Merch via Amazon then you must list what type of business you are, i.e. education etc.  Then you will have to wait for a confirmation via email as far as I can tell it should be smooth sailing from there!

Comment: What? Are you sure that you are telling me about developer api of Merch?

Comment: @Achilles have you found the correct API? I am also looking for that.